# How can I get the same values from the SEC API?

Tags: sec

I am trying to get the same Depreciation and Amortization (Total) we can get for AAPL on Seeking Alpha and QuickFS for instance. Here is what is their values:

[image]

However, what I am getting using the SEC EDGAR API is this: [image]

Those values are from the DepreciationAmortizationAndAccretionNet tag. I got mostly the same value except for the years 2018 to 2023 where I got NaN. It is not an error, this is really what I got from the SEC API.

How can I get the same values from the SEC API?

Comment: NAN (not a number) means that whatever you are getting back isn't in the expected format. I'd start by adding debugging output to your code to see what is actually being returned before you fail to convert it to scientific notation. This seems to be a coding problem more than a financial problem.

Comment: @keshlam I have debugged it and it seems it is related to the tag name. Not even sure how QuickFS and Alpha Seek got their numbers, but I am not sure how they compute it or get it.

Comment: Ask the EDGAR user community and/or the folks who support it. That's where you'll find the expertise in using that tool.